# How to iterate through a list and sum members together

Tags: python, list, python-3.3

Using Python 3.3, I have a list as such:

```
>>> ls
[250313, 242517, 243788, 1606025, 1566365, 1573483]
```

I need a `for` loop or built-in function to iterate over this, summing three integers together at a time.

I would like the end result to look like this:

```
>>> newls 
[736618, 4745873]
```

It seems like `itertools` or `sum` would be helpful for this, but I can't seem to figure it out yet.

Comment: What do you want to happen if `len(ls)` isn't a multiple of three?

Comment: @jwodder That is checked earlier in the code, at this point the list should always be divisible by three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the sum of each consecutive three-element sublist of `ls` as so:

```
newls = [sum(ls[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(ls), 3)]
```

Note that, if `len(ls)` is not a multiple of three, the last one or two elements of `ls` will be summed together to make the last element of `newls`.  To ignore any trailing elements that aren't part of a group of three, do:

```
newls = [sum(ls[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(ls) - len(ls) % 3, 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Reshape your array into a matrix of dimensionality len(ls)/3 by 3, and then sum elements in each row.

```
import numpy as np
result = np.array(ls).reshape((-1,3)).sum(axis = 1)
```